# Calling in the main method

Tags: java

I am using **bufferedwriter** on a file and did my code. But my issue is calling it to the main method. How would I do that? This is the name of the method:

```
public void writerof(final String filePath, final int n) throws IOException.....
```

So in the main method would I say:

```
writerof("file.txt", 6)
```

I get an error on the writeof part it says writeof is undefined.

Also these are my catch and final blocks:

```
    catch (IOException ioe) {

        ioe.printStackTrace();

    }


    finally {

        if (writer != null) writer.close();
    }

    }
```

Any errors?

Comment: if `writerof` is not `static` then you need an instance of your `Object` as `MyObject obj = new MyObject()` and invoke it on `obj`. If you don´t need one define the method as `static`.

Comment: you'll need to show more of your code. is it in the same class? also, you'll need to call it as an instance method, through an instance, or make the method static

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make it static like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            writerof("file.txt", 6);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void writerof(final String filePath, final int n) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("my method here");
    }
```

---

or maybe a little better:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        MyClass z = new MyClass();
        try {
            z.writerof("file.txt", 6);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public  void writerof(final String filePath, final int n) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("my method here");
    }
```

Comment: thanks i fixed it. One question. I included the try block and finally/catch blocks in my other method not in the main method. Although the error showed to include try block in the main so I did. So should i still keep the catch and finally in my other method or will getting rid off it not work?

Answer (score 3):

As your method signature says that its not `static` but our `main` is a `static method` so it can't call it.
So either make it `static` or **create an object of that class** in `main` then call it.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 problems in your code (if I got it correctly):

- First problem - you calling object's method in static context. You need make this method static or create object of this class and call this method of these object.
- Second problem - you calling method that throws exception while I'm not sure that you throw it out from main method (you should throws it out from main method or surround with try-catch block).